# trying to import pyodbc library in IronPython in C#

Tags: c#, python, odbc

I am trying to embed IronPhyton scripting language into the C# project. I am hoping to let users write code with IronPhyton in my C# project.

I need to let users get data from database with IronPhyton, but I couldnt find a way to import the pyodbc library. Where should I put the library files in order for IronPyhton to make a connection? Should I add the library into the Visual Studio? I am lost. The library is not a DLL file, it is bunch of .pdb files.

this code below is IronPhyton.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SOME-PC;DATABASE=my_db")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot use Python libraries that use native libraries (DLLs or other binary files) in IronPython. Instead of trying to use `pyodbc` use .NET ways of connecting to database. See http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Databases_with_Odbc . I have tested it with Oracle ODBC connections and it works.

Similar problem is in Jython where you can use JDBC drivers or pure Python libaries.

Comment: is there a connection string for ms-sql

Comment: But my favourite ODBC connection string is DSN: http://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn/  because it is very simple.